# Append "," to end of the desired string in notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have quite a large list of words in a txt file and I'm trying to do a regex find and replace in Notepad++. I need to append comma(,) at the end of "local" string.

So that:

```
english: "About"
local: " " 
english: "Accessibility"
local: " "
```

become

```
english: "About"
local: " ", 
english: "Accessibility"
local: " ",
```

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex. Make sure that `.` maches newline is unchecked.

```
Find: ^local.*\K
Replace: ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Find: ^local: "(.*)"
Replace: local: "\1",
```